# Число в js не увеличивается, а просто присоединяется к текущему

Tags: javascript, html, input

У меня есть input типа число. Есть две функции, отвечающие за изменение его значения: прибавить, вычесть. Так вот, с вычитанием всё удачно проходит и число уменьшается, как надо. Но когда складываешь эти числа, то они не суммируются, а просто прибавляются (1+1=11).

Что делать?

```
var am = document.getElementById('amount');
var count_machine = document.getElementById('count');
var count;

m_but.onclick = function() { 
    count = count_machine.value;
    am.value -= count;
}

p_but.onclick = function() {
    count = count_machine.value;
    am.value += count;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Когда вы получаете значение из инпута оно являеться не числом, а строкой. 
Попробуйте добавить явное приведение типа при получении значения:

```
var am = document.getElementById('amount');
var count_machine = document.getElementById('count');
var count;

m_but.onclick = function() { 
    count = +count_machine.value;
    am.value -= count;
}

p_but.onclick = function() {
    count = +count_machine.value;
    am.value = +am.value + count;
}
```

Comment: т.е. я должен поставить там плюсы?? Почему-то не работает данный метод((

Comment: Скорее всего `am.value += count;` тоже строка. Попробуйте заменить на: `am.value = +am.value + count;`

Comment: С Новым Годом! =)

Comment: к чему эти сложности? `var am = Number(document.getElementById('amount').value);`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не вижу, на самом деле, никаких сложностей! Всё достаточно прозрачно и удобочитаемо.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков - Это второй способ решения этой же задачи :)

Comment: @Pon4iPay Сложности в том что поведение вот этих плясок с бубном сложно угадать, есть механизм который предназначен для разрешения таких проблем, и в ответе явно им не пахнет(**явное приведение типов**).

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко Это пляски с бубном, которые однажды приведут к печальному результату, ибо в вашем коде нет гарантии получения числа.

Comment: Явное приведение к типу используя конструктор Number, это лучшее решение, потому что видно что чем является и гарантированно на выходе получите число.

Answer (score 6):

В JS есть возможность явно приводить типы, советую при операциях использовать эти возможности, поможет избежать вот таких вот глюков. Пример:

```
var am = document.getElementById('amount');
var count_machine = document.getElementById('count');
var count;

m_but.onclick = function() { 
    count = Number(count_machine.value);
    am.value =Number(am.value) - count;
}

p_but.onclick = function() {
    count = Number(count_machine.value);
    am.value =Number(am.value) + count;
}
```

Comment: Данное решение содержит небольшую ошибку: оно не обновит значение инпута, так как `am` в данном случае число, а не ссылка на инпут.

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко Да, именно так. Если вам нужно обновление - используйте длинный вариант записи. `am.value = Number(am.value)+Number(count_machine.value);` исправил ответ =)